# distributing graph nodes into buckets

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a adjacency matrix `n`x`n`. Each node of the graph has `m` outgoing edges and I want to distribute these nodes into `b` buckets.
Each bucket should hold a minimum of `l` and a maximum of `u` nodes (`u`x`b` >= `n`). Each node inside the bucket should have at least one outgoing edge to another node inside the bucket.

I feel that I am missing the best angle to solve this.
How would you approach this?

Comment: Do you have some expectation about uniformity (randomness) or will any solution do?

Comment: Can you please explain this one " Each node inside the bucket should have at least one outgoing edge to another node inside the bucket." 

if I rephrase that one, does it mean "Each bucket should have at least two different nodes which have an edge between them."

Comment: @AhmadFaiyaz No, that's not enough. For every node inside a bucket at least one outgoing edge needs to point to a node that is inside the same bucket.

Comment: @rici The more interconnected nodes inside a bucket the better.

Comment: How do you check the final solution's correctness. All nodes go in one bucket vs 2 nodes per bucket, which would be more correct? Is the number of buckets pre-defined?

Comment: gc7 See above: There are b buckets and each bucket needs to hold a minimum of l and maximum of u nodes. To check for correctness you iterated the buckets and check the outgoing edges of each node. At least one of them needs to point to a node inside the same bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Start by separating the graph into connected components this can be done in O(n) time and memory by performing a depth-first or breadth-first search.

If any nodes are not connected to another node then a solution is not possible.

Start from the leaves of each DFS/BFS tree (i.e. nodes connected to only one other node) and split each connected component into pairs (or triplets) of adjacent nodes. Each pair (or triplet) should go into the next bucket with the fewest number of nodes in it.

```
      o   o
     / \  |
o   o   o o     |    |    |    |    |    |
|  / \ /  |     |    |    |    |    |    |
o o   o   o     |    |    |    |    |    |
 \ \ /   /      |____|    |____|    |____|
  --o----      Bucket 1  Bucket 2  Bucket 3
```

Remove 2 nodes from the left leaf.

```
      o   o
     / \  |
a   o   o o     |a   |    |    |    |    |
|  / \ /  |     ||   |    |    |    |    |
a o   o   o     |a   |    |    |    |    |
 \ \ /   /      |____|    |____|    |____|
  --o----      Bucket 1  Bucket 2  Bucket 3
```

Remove 2 nodes from the right leaf.

```
      o   b
     / \  |
    o   o b     |a   |    |b   |    |    |
   / \ /  |     ||   |    ||   |    |    |
  o   o   o     |a   |    |b   |    |    |
   \ /   /      |____|    |____|    |____|
    o----      Bucket 1  Bucket 2  Bucket 3
```

Then remove the final degree 1 vertex and its neighbour:

```
      o    
     / \   
    o   o       |a   |    |b   |    |c   |
   / \ /        ||   |    ||   |    ||   |
  o   o   c     |a   |    |b   |    |c   |
   \ /   /      |____|    |____|    |____|
    c----      Bucket 1  Bucket 2  Bucket 3
```

This creates a new degree 1 vertex in the remaining sub-graph so remove that and its adjacent vertex:

```
      o    
     / \   
    d   o       |a d |    |b   |    |c   |
   / \ /        || | |    ||   |    ||   |
  d   o         |a d |    |b   |    |c   |
                |____|    |____|    |____|
               Bucket 1  Bucket 2  Bucket 3
```

There are only 3 vertices left, if it will fit in a bucket then put it into the bucket - otherwise move a pair from the bucket with the smallest number of items to the bucket with the next lowest number of items and add the triplet in its place.

```
      e    
       \   
        e       |a d |    |e e |    |c b |
       /        || | |    |\ / |    || | |
      e         |a d |    | e  |    |c b |
                |____|    |____|    |____|
               Bucket 1  Bucket 2  Bucket 3
```

The only issue will be when you get star-like connected components

```
  o   o
   \ /
 o--o--o
   / \
  o   o
```

Then the entire connected component will need to go into the same bucket as you cannot split the graph by removing a pair of triplet of adjacent vertices without having single disjoint vertices remaining. This you can check for by testing whether if you remove a pair there are other adjacent vertices that were degree one and if so add them to the pair.

Comment: Wow - that's a great answer. I guess I need to give this a try to see if I understand it correctly. Will report back. But thanks for that already.